# Code duplication - swift3

Tags: swift3

swift3 noob here so please excuse me if this is a stupid question.

I have come across this issue few times but have been unable to resolve it. How can I avoid code duplication in the below.

```
@IBAction func logOutButton(_ sender: Any) {

    var userEntered = usernameText.text!

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")

    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username = %@", "xyz")

    do {

        let results = try context.fetch(request)

    } catch {

        print ("Delete failed")
    }

}

@IBAction func submitButton(_ sender: Any) {
    var users = [String]()
    var userEntered = usernameText.text!
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext


    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")


    let newValue = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Users", into: context)

    newValue.setValue(userEntered, forKey: "username")

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        try context.save()
```

As you can see the code below is duplicated in both buttons. How can I avoid this? I have tried to write it in a method but I must be doing something wrong and that throws a lot of errors.

```
    var userEntered = usernameText.text!
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext


    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")
```

Thank you

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what errors you are getting.

Comment: Why not put the code you are using multiple times in a function then call that function?

Comment: Use a `NSManagedObject` subclass, it avoids a lot of boilerplate code. Then you can write `let request = Users.fetchRequest()`

Answer (score 1):

Just make a return function that returns an `NSFetchRequest`.

```
func getFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")
    return request
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function returning NSFetchRequest

```
func getRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
  var userEntered = usernameText.text!
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")
}
```

Then your actions will be like

```
@IBAction func logOutButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let request = getRequest()
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username = %@", "xyz")
    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(request)
    } catch {
        print ("Delete failed")
    }
}
```